# Possible to optimize pattern-matching code segment in one line?

Tags: f#

I am wondering if there is a way to write this line without piping h to calcVol function twice?

```
| h :: t when (h |> calcVol) > maxVol -> maxLoop t (h |> calcVol)
```

Where h is a tuple containing three dimensions, and calcVol returns a float value.

I know that I could explicitly define a vol value as:

`| h :: t ->
    let vol = calcVol h
    if vol > maxVol then...`

I am wondering if there is a way to do this nicely in one line?

Comment: It's challenging to give a definitive answer without more context but maybe an active pattern might help.

Comment: Don't know if this will help but, It's part of a recursive loop that uses matching and looks at the elements of a list. It will recursively go through the whole list and return the max value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the uses of `vol` were before the arrow, you could do this:

```
| h :: t when let vol = (h |> calcVol) in vol > maxVol -> // Something
```

But `let` assignments in the `when` clause left of the arrow do not carry over to the right-hand side. Demonstration:

```
let f x = x + 5
let l = [1; 2]
match l with
| a :: b when let y = f a in y = 6 -> "Six"
| _ -> "Other"
```

This works, and returns `"Six"`. But:

```
let f x = x + 5
let l = [1; 2]
match l with
| a :: b when let y = f a in y = 6 -> sprintf "Six = %d" y
| _ -> "Other"
```

This does *not* work, producing the error:

> error FS0039: The value or constructor `'y'` is not defined.

So unfortunately, **you can't have the one-line version you want** and you'll have to go with the longer approach (with a `let` followed by an `if`, as you demonstrate in the second half of your answer).

Answer (score 1):

Using active patterns a solution could look like this:

```
let calcVol v = v

let (|MaxVol|) maxVol = function
| [] -> (maxVol, [])
| h :: t -> ((max (calcVol h) maxVol), t)

let rec maxLoop list m =
    match list with
    | [] -> m
    | MaxVol m (c, t) -> maxLoop t c

let vs = [ -1; 42; 3 ]

maxLoop vs System.Int32.MinValue // 42
```

Another possibility with better readability might be to first calculate the volumes (e.g. by `map`ping) and then find the maximum. Difficult to tell without the complete code...